Implied Vol under CEV model
Consider the following steps:

Suppose the underlying equity follows a CEV model $dS_t = rS_t dt + \sigma S^{0.5} dW_t$.
Use the above CEV model to simulate Monte Carlo paths and price a large set (across different maturities and strikes) of European and American prices.
Backout the implied volatilities, for each $(K,T)$ pair using the options prices. By implied volatility, I mean the $\sigma$ in $dS_t = rS_tdt + \sigma S_t dW_t$ to match the option prices (either American or European).

My question is: Is the implied volatility surface using the European options the same as the one using the American options?

This might be helpful: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8070/different-exercise-style-options-on-same-underlying/63556#63556

Isn’t this question circular ? You have generated option prices using a model with vol parameter $\sigma$ and then you ask what implied $\sigma$ would have generated them ?

@dm63, I'm trying to make a distinction between the $\sigma$ in CEV (the vol from the actual dynamics) and the $\sigma$ in the GBM (the BS implied vol). If in #1, the model is GBM, I agree that this is circular; but with a CEV, or even some other dynamics, I'm not sure.

Ok thx I see it now
